# Deletar múltiplas linhas dinamicamente com PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Digamos que eu tenha uma tabela de usuários (`id | nome`) e que onde eles são listados (*client-side*) eu possa selecionar vários deles e deletá-los ao mesmo tempo.

Como eu poderia fazer isso num banco MySQL utilizando PDO?

Eu sei que o MySQL permite o uso da cláusula `IN` que serviria para esse tipo de query. Ex:

```
DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE id IN (37,45,58) # deletaria os ids 37, 45 e 58
```

O problema é que como os `ids` seriam dinâmicos e o PDO utiliza *prepared-statements*, não sei como procederia com o código nele. Imagino que seria algo como:

```
$query = $pdo->prepare("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE id IN :ids");
$query->bindParam(':ids', [37,45,58]); #array de ids vindo de um $_POST, por exemplo.
$query->execute();
```

Teria alguma forma de fazer algo como o código acima, com valores dinâmicos?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Podes fazer uso da função [`str_repeat()`](http://php.net/str_repeat) do PHP para gerar uma *string* repetindo o `?` por cada ID presente na tua matriz:

```php
$ids = //... seja lá como você recupera os ids

$mParams = str_repeat('?,', count($ids) - 1) . '?';
$sth = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE id IN ($mParams)");
$sth->execute($ids);
```

Por exemplo se tivesse um

```
$ids = [11, 23, 34, 47];
```

O `str_repeat` vai gerar uma saída:

> ?,?,?,?

Ficando

```
$sth = $db->prepare("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE id IN (?,?,?,?)");
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado.

Comment: @Zuul Obrigado pela edição

Answer (score 1):

nas minhas consultas PDO utilizo sempre **parâmetros nomeados** então não é possível usar o "coringa" `?`, uso o seguinte trecho de código

```
$ids = array(); // sua variável
$sql = 'SELECT ...';
$parameters = array(); // variável de parâmetros passada para execute()
$in = array();
foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
  $keyname = ':id' . $key;
  $parameters[$keyname] = $value;
  array_push($in, $keyname);
}
$sql .= 'WHERE id IN (' . join(', ', $in) . ')';
```